# Sixth derivative?

Tags: calculus

What is the sixth derivative of: $f(x)=x^6$?

---

Book says the correct answer is $e^x$, but I'm getting $720$.
Which is the correct answer?

Comment: Of course 720. Which book that is?

Comment: It might be that past editions asked for $e^x$ and thy forgot to update the answer.

Comment: @ethan: Not if it is a function of a single variable. Ever seen the notation $f'(x)$ before?

Comment: @Ethan: That's absolutely absurd. What if he's using a special notation where "$6$" really stands for the number $42$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most definitely right.

Answer (score 2):

Surely you're correct and we have in the general case
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}x^n=n!$$

**Notice** If the question of the book: what's the sixth derivative of $f(x)=e^x$? then the answer is $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Either a book is wrong, or you misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice: physics books are full of errors. I could not tell you the time we spent trying to get the"right" answer before a teaching assistant quickly realized it was a typo or else.

Comment: All the books have mistakes, not only physics ones.

Comment: yes, but the consequences for an individual are different if it a regular versus a textbook

Comment: I've seen mistakes/typos in math textbooks too, so your rant on physics books is too single-sided.

Comment: I mean that any textbook (math, phys, biol, etc) with typos can mean a nightmare for the student, just that.